# How to use accessToken of google plus to sign out user in android from different activity

Tags: android, logout, access-token

In Android Application,

In one activity, I can sign in using google plus as described here :
    https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

But i want to do log out from google plus from different activity.
So When I click on Log out button then i am executing this code...But here isConnected() method always return false because user is no longer connected..So how can i connect user using AccessToken Which i store from first activity?

```
 if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "User is disconnected.");
    }
```

So how can i use access token to log out user from different activity ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you found a solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

The signin is for the entire app so you can sign out anywhere in the app.

Signout activity.

Initialize the GoogleApiClient object in your Activity.onCreate handler.

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .build();
}
```

Invoke GoogleApiClient.connect during Activity.onStart .

```
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


//process sign out in click of button.
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
      mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();  //may not be needed
    }
  }
}
```